# jquery datepicker flickers when displayed programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to create a date range layout in a form.  I am using [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). When user selects first date, second date should open automatically. However, the second datepicker flickers first, i.e. it opens then closes then opens again. This is in IE8/Win, in FF15/Win, it opens then closes and that's it, it disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a timing issue. Try entering a small delay via setTimeout like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L4Sx3/3/)**.

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#calEndDate").datepicker('show');},10);
```

Comment: ah that's more simple than the solution I was going to post. I was wrapping the calEndDate in a function, but using the setTimeout to give focus to the element to trigger the datepicker. Not really sure much about why setting a delay on the success callback works though.